# Updating Context from a Nested Component is not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, I am trying to pass theme string and and toggleTheme function from parent to child using Context API in react.I am practicing example from React Doc with little modification https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
my code is as following:

```
import React from 'react';
const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: 'light',
  toggleTheme: () => {}
})
class MouseTracker2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleTheme = () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        theme:
          state.theme === 'dark'
            ? 'light'
            : 'dark',
      }));
    };
    this.state={
      theme: 'dark',
      toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme 
      }
    } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
          <Abc />
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      </div>
    )
  }
} 
class Abc extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {({theme,toggleTheme}) => {return(<Def theme={theme} onClick=            
 {toggleTheme} />)}}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
class Def extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>efgh</p>
        <div>{this.props.theme}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default MouseTracker2
```

In above Code, Context is passing string from parent to child properly. However, it is not passing function from parent to child. 
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toggleTheme` function is passed on to `Def` by the name `onClick` and hence `this.props.toggleTheme` is unavailable and can be accessed by `this.props.onClick`

```
class MouseTracker2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleTheme = () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        theme: state.theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"
      }));
    };
    this.state = {
      theme: "dark",
      toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
          <Abc />
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Abc extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
          {({ theme, toggleTheme }) => {
            return <Def theme={theme} onClick={toggleTheme} />;
          }}
        </ThemeContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Def extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>efgh</p>
        <div>{this.props.theme}</div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/73jkjq57lq)**

Comment: please, can you explain why your example and react doc example include empty function on `const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: "light",
  toggleTheme: () => {}
});`  I tried to remove it and The code working without it so what it play here

Comment: I saw another example here https://codesandbox.io/s/p9p4jmqkq7. and the same when I remove `toggleTheme: () => {}` it affect nothing ... why it added ... thanks